# What to do when I'm incapable of finding a partner to marry due to a medical condition?

Tags: nikah, sex

I have been suffering with two medical issues since childhood and am on life saving medicines which I have to take three times a day. Due to my medical issues, I have been rejected marriage proposals several times. It is very apparent that the medical issues that I face would not make me an ideal candidate for marriage.

Islam always refers to sex with the context of marriage that pre marital sex is forbidden. Islam does not give any opinion about fulfilling sexual desires when marriage is impossible.

I have consulted with various Islamic scholars majority of whom have been unable to find an answer whereas the answers relate to avoiding sexual desires rather than a solution to meeting them. One such Islamic scholar advised to carry out a Niyat (intention) in salat that since marriage is impossible due to medical issues, I shall fulfil my sexual desires for which I shall not be answerable in Hereafter.

I seek advise on the same.

Answer (score 3):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Islam does not allow sex without marriage.

> Narrated `Uqba bin Amir: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "From among all
>   the conditions which you have to fulfill, the conditions which make it
>   legal for you to have sexual relations (i.e. the marriage contract)
>   have the greatest right to be fulfilled."([Bukhari](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/54/10))

You said you have been rejected several marriage proposals but you could find In Sha Allah someone if you try to find someone with the same issues as it would be hard for the other person too to find someone perfectly fit.May Allah Swt make it easier for you.

**Three groups of people Allah obliged Himself to help them: Mujahid in the cause of Allah, a worker to pay his debt, and the one who wants to marry to live a chaste life." (Tirmidhi)**

There is no niyat in salat which would make your sex without marriage permissible kindly ask the mufti regarding this statement.

Temporary marriage or Mutah was abrogated by Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him and it is not allowed in Islam now (Sunni view),

**Narrated `Ali bin Abi Talib (Ra):
On the day of Khaibar, Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade the Mut'a (i.e. temporary marriage) and the eating of donkey-meat.([Bukhari](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/64/256))**

**Rabi' b. Sabra reported on the authority of his father that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade on the Day of Victory to contract temporary marriage with women.([Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/16/30))**

**It was narrated from Al-Hasan and 'Abdullah, the sons of Muhammad, from their father, that 'Ali heard that a man did not see anything wrong with Mut'ah (temporary marriage). He said:
"You are confused, the Messenger of Allah forbade it, and the meat of domestic donkeys on the day of Khaibar."([Nasai](http://www.sunnah.com/nasai/26/170))**

**It was narrated that Ibn 'Umar said:
"When 'Umar bin Khattab (Ra) was appointed caliph, he addressed the people and said: 'The Messenger of Allah permitted temporary marriage for us three times, then he forbade it. By Allah, If I hear of any married person entering a temporary marriage, I will stone him to death, unless he can bring me four witnesses who will testify that the Messenger of Allah, allowed it after he forbade it'."[(Ibn Majah)](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1262820)**

Also read [this](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/01/25/the-ruling-of-temporary-marriages-muta-and-the-importance-of-avoiding-arguments/) about Mutah

Sex without marriage is Zina is Islam,

> And do not approach adultery – it is indeed a shameful deed; and a
>   very evil way.([Quran 17:32](http://tanzil.net/#17:32))

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Temporary marriage is allowed in Islam. It is the exception and a last resort when permanent marriage is not possible or things become extremely difficult to bear for the one who cannot get married.  The legality of mut'ah is stated in hadith and the Holy Qur'an(4:24; 5:87)) In al-Bukhari and al-Muslim you can find many hadith about the permissibility of temporary marriage during the time of the Holy Prophet. It was the second caliph who changed it to a prohibited act.

Comment: I suggest you add this Hadith in your answer *Three groups of people Allah obliged Himself to help them: Mujahid in the cause of Allah, a worker to pay his debt, and the one who wants to marry to live a chaste life." (Tirmidhi 1661, Nisai 3120, Ibn e Majah 2518, Ahmed 9637)*

Comment: @Noor JazakAllah for your references ,I am aware of this fact that it is allowed in views of shia but there is consensus among sunni scholars that it was abrogated by Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him ,So I mentioned above that it is Sunni view.

Comment: @Believer JazakAllah for your nice suggestion I would add this In Sha Allah.